# MuleSoft: Sum line items and group by ID

Tags: mule, integration, mule-studio

I am new to integration and MuleSoft so I need your help. I have a flat file with different invoice line items per salesID, like this:

```
SalesOrderID    OrderQty    UnitPrice

43659   70  2024.994

43659   70  2024.994

43660   1   419.4589

43660   1   874.794

43661   1   809.76
```

I want to insert total invoice amount and quantity in another CSV file using Mule, something like this:

```
SalesOrderID    OrderQty    UnitPrice

43659   140 4049.988

43660   2   1294.4589

43661   1   809.76
```

I know how to do this in informatica,but im trying to figure out a way to do this in MuleSoft. How can I sum up all the line items and group them by SalesOrderID? Any help/clue will be really appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, let me explain my personal favourite assuming you are using Mule community edition.

Use the superb library: [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/cell_processors.html), it will allow you not only to parse the data (including those dot numbers) but also validate it and give back an exact report on why the file is broken in case it is.

This could be done in a transformer that transform the inbound stream and return either a map of maps (or even better a iterator that handles the whole thing but this is more difficult) or a custom exception with the error report.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this requirement is one that faces Mule developers even today, it's useful to see a solution based on the Mule 4.x runtime and Dataweave 2.x.

- If the data came from a file or is otherwise a monolithic stream of text, use the splitBy() function to get an array of text lines.

  payload splitBy '\n'
- remove the first line as the headers should not be calculated

  payload[1 to -1] // this is my favorite way to do it
- Now use the reduce() function to iterate over each of the lines in turn, updating the accumulator each time to account for quantity and price.

Hopefully that helps